# Problem using Multires sculpting!

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, multiresolution

I am trying to Sculpt a character using multires and i tried to shape general forms in lower Sub and move on to higher subdivisions step by step but after forming the basic shape that I wanted subdividing cause this artifact!

[image: Before Subdivision]

[image: After Subdivision]

**Notes:**

-Rot scale applied

-Base mesh did not changed in edit mode

-apply base makes it worse

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: i have the same problem as you. Blender 2.8 from 11 oct. My model's eyes and hands becobe mess after i make "Apply Base". Do you found any solutions yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was modifying overall shapes of a pre defined basemesh using "grab" brush.

changes in major shapes of a basemesh using grab brush creates artifact using multires 
subdivision